# Control radio-controlled sockets with the Raspberrypi via a website with apache2

Tags: php, html, linux, raspberry-pi, apache2

I want to control my radio-controlled sockets with the raspberry pi via a website with apache2.
But nothing happens when I click on the buttons on the website. I also get no error.
My code is:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>DIY smart home</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post">
<input type="submit" value="LED desk on" name="led_desk_on">
</form>

<form method="post">
<input type="submit" value="LED desk off" name="led_desk_off">
</form>
</br>

<form method="post" >
<input type="submit" value="LED bed on" name="led_bed_on">
</form>

<form method="post" >
<input type="submit" value="LED bed off" name="led_bed_off">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['led_desk_on'])) {
        exec("sudo /home/pi/steckdosen/raspberry-remote/./send 01010 1 1");
}

if(isset($_POST['led_desk_off'])) {
        exec("sudo /home/pi/steckdosen/raspberry-remote/./send 01010 1 0");
}

if(isset($_POST['led_bed_on'])) {
        exec("sudo /home/pi/steckdosen/raspberry-remote/./send 01010 2 1");
}

if(isset($_POST['led_bed_off'])) {
        exec("sudo /home/pi/steckdosen/raspberry-remote/./send 01010 2 0");
?>

</body>

</html>
```

The website looks like this:
[website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpNLZ.png)

When I click on the buttons nothing happens.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. It's `<br>` not `</br>`. In addition, the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately it doesn't work either

Comment: First, see if your command works if you execute it in the Terminal, outside of apache `sudo /home/pi/steckdosen/raspberry-remote/./send 01010 1 1`

Comment: Then see which user is executing your PHP by execing `whoami > /tmp/whoami` and see if that user can `sudo`.

Comment: The command works fine and I did what you told me to do and this is the user www-data. I think this user has no permissions to go in that directory. But how can I change that?

Comment: I also moved the folder into /var/www/html/ but this doesn't work either

Comment: It depends on your environment and security needs. If it's just a private, home network, you could change your `httpd.conf` so that the `user` isn't set to `www-data` but stays as root.

Comment: I did it! I changed the user in the apache config file